# How to move to the next source offered by helm mini?

Tags: helm

Is there a way to jump in helm mini directly to the next source? Is it also possible to fold and unfold a source-list?

Comment: You can customize the order of the sources in helm mini via `helm-mini-default-sources`. You can jump to next source in helm by using `C-o` (`helm-next-source`). I don't think it's possible to fold/unfold a source at least for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to jump in helm mini directly to the next source?

Yes, you can do it via <kbd>C-o</kbd> (`helm-next-source`) in all helm commands. The following is copied from helm's documentation (you can access it via <kbd>C-h m</kbd> in helm).

```
** Helm's Basic Operations and Default Key Bindings

| Key     | Alternative Keys | Command                                                   |
|---------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------|
| Left    |                  | Previous Source                                           |
| Right   | C-o              | Next Source                                               |
```

> Is it also possible to fold and unfold a source-list?

No, it is impossible.

Comment: I think that left and right arrows also work.

Comment: You "think"? Source?  Please don't think. People are googling solutions not guesses. Source your claims please.

Comment: Even without a source, this comment was helpful.  I just tried it out and it worked, I'm okay not having a source!  Thank you.